# Java - Squish Image/BufferedImage to Four Points

Tags: java, image, graphics

I have been doing some graphics recently and I ran into a problem. I can't seem to find a good way to squish an image between four points. It sounds like a simple operation and if I have just been missing it feel free to point it out. Here's what I ideally want:
[image: Before/After]

It's also worth noting that the entire image has to be squished into the new polygon not just cropped. 
EDIT: My code looks something like this:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel {
    public static Image image;
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static Main main;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File imageFile = new File("test.png");
        image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        main = new Main();
        frame.add(main);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int p1x = 10;
        int p1y = 10;

        int p2x = 400;
        int p2y = 450;

        int p3x = 360;
        int p3y = 23;

        int p4x = 23;
        int p4y = 500;

        /*////////////////

        Draw the image between all of the defined points.

        /*////////////////
    }
}
```

Comment: The term you’re looking for is [shear](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getShearInstance-double-double-).  Since you haven’t shown any of your code, I can’t say for sure how to apply the transform, but you probably want to pass your BufferedImage to the [Graphics2D.drawRenderedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawRenderedImage-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-) method.

Comment: This is basically a maths problem. If you can't find a Java solution, you might want to search for language-agnostic solutions, which can be converted to use Java's graphics transform classes. If your new polygon will keep parallel lines parallel, then the plain old Java classes Graphics2D and AffineTransform will do it. If your new polygon may have non-parallel lines, then you will need a non-affine transform, which you will not get from Graphics/Graphics2D. I believe JavaFX's PerspectiveTransform will work. I'm afraid I don't know the necessary maths to construct the transform though.